# Firebase realtime database Rules to filter lists

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I want to save some stuff on a firebase real time database and only allow users access to elements that contain certain values.

More specificly i want to have events as a list and users saved as a list:
-users have their uid and roles (e.g. "admin" , "any" , etc)
-events have some data that should only be allowed for users that have one or more of the specified roles

How would i go and filter the list using rules?

Comment: See the Firebase documentation for [query based security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules). If you're having a hard time making these work, edit your question to show what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so thanks to Frank van Puffelen i do now know that what i wanted to do (wich was filter data cia rules) does not work